# How to connect voltage protection relay to contactor?

Tags: relay, contactor

Could you help me connect a voltage protection relay (VPR) to a contactor? I'm not sure how to connect the relay output terminals (NO, NC, COM, etc.) to contactor control terminals A1 and A2 in the wiring diagram below.

[image: Wiring diagram for connection of VPR-voltage protection relay to contactor]

- VPR (voltage protection relay) used is 3 phase type. Manufacturer said L2 and L3 can be shorted to L1 for use in single phase.
- Contactor is single phase, NO type.

I would like the contactor to close when there is no fault detected and for it to open when there is a fault.

- VPR [datasheet](https://www.enika.cz/data/files/produkty/komponenty/mereni-a-regulace/900VPR-2-280_520V.pdf)
- Contactor [datasheet](https://www.schneider-electric.com/en/product/A9C20862/ict-63a-2no-220...240v-50hz-contactor/)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

W.r.t. diagram in question, the following connections must be made (in addition to existing connections) for the NO contactor to close when there is no fault detected by VPR and for the NO contactor to open when there is fault detected by VPR.

- L1 to COM
- NO to A1
- N to A2